# Proving that the absolute value function does not have second weak derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

Define $f(x) = |x|$. It can be shown that $f$ has a weak derivative

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}1 &: x > 0\\\ 0 &: x = 0 \\\ -1 &: x < 0\end{cases}$$

I'm trying to show that $f$ does not have a second weak derivative, but I'm not sure about all the details, specifically what a contradiction in the attempted proof by contradiction below should be.

By the way of contradiction, assume that some $h\in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies

$$\forall \phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}):\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x)g(x)dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)h(x)dx$$

For any $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathrm{supp}(\phi)\subset (0,\infty)$ (similar for  $\mathrm{supp}(\phi)\subset (-\infty, 0)$), we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x)g(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x)dx = \left[\phi(x)\right]_0^\infty  = 0$$

as $\mathrm{supp}(\phi)$ is a compact subset of $(0, \infty)$.

For $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi(0)\neq 0$, we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x)g(x)dx = -\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x) dx + \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x)dx = 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x)dx = -2\phi(0)$$

So on the one hand, on the space $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, the supposed weak derivative of $g$ must be zero. And the weak derivative is unique up to a set of Lebesgue measure zero, so (**and this is something I'm not sure about**) since the weak derivative of $g$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, it also exists in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and hence by uniqueness it must be zero a.e. in $\mathbb{R}$. But now by the last integral equality, for any $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi(0)\neq 0$ we get a contradiction.

So I'm not that comfortable with embedding/extension type results, and therefore my mathematical awareness screams at me when I say out loud parts after the bolded text. Is the argument good enough, or is there some caveat I have not seen?

Comment: Never heard of "weak derivate". The function $f(x)=|x|$ is anyway not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @CartesianBear Since you can relate the distributional derivative of $g(x)$ with the Dirac-$\delta$, I think you'll this post very useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922708/dirac-delta-distribution-integration-against-locally-integrable-function

Comment: you don't need to distinguish where the support of $\phi$ is (or whether it vanishes at $0$). Just take a general $\phi$ and integrate by parts. Then from the expression you obtain try to get a contradiction

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike I don't think I know how to do it that way: I somehow need to argue that the supposed second weak derivative is zero almost everywhere, and to me this can only be done by considering localization of the supports of the test functions.

Comment: @Peter Well now you have! To my knowledge fold in Sobolev spaces call such local $L^1$ functions defined with integration by parts as the weak derivative.

Comment: @CartesianBear: I think you should add what you mean by weak derivative. In the sense of distributions, $f(x)=|x|$ has a second derivative which can be seen to be $2\delta_0$.